# How to replace the last character of particular strings in a dataframe column?

Tags: r, for-loop, stringr

I have a dataframe which includes a column of identifier codes. Where the code ends in a 0, I want to replace it with a 1.

Through a lot of trial and error I have a for loop which almost works. It works when there is only one code which ends in a 0 and it's in the last row of the dataframe. If there's another row of data, the for loop doesn't produce the desired output.

```
library(stringr)

df_a <- data.frame(a = c("02.1.1", "02.1.1.0"))
df_b <- data.frame(a = c("02.1.1", "02.1.1.0", "02.1.2"))

for (i in nrow(df_a)){
  df_a$adj <- ""
  df_a$code_adj <- ""
  if (str_sub(df_a[i, "a"], -1, -1) == "0"){
    df_a[i, "adj"] <- "1"
    df_a[i, "code_adj"] <- paste0(str_sub(df_a[i, "a"], 1, -2), df_a[i, "adj"])
  } 
}
```

When I run the for loop on the dataframe df_a, it produces the desired result. When I run it on df_b it does not.

I'm open to better way's of approaching this problem but I would also like to know why the for loop behaves as it does on the different dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a function with `sub` and reuse it on multiple datasets.  Match the 0 at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with 1 for the specific column in the dataset, update the column and return the dataset

```
f1 <- function(dat, colNm) {
      dat[[colNm]] <- sub("0$", "1", dat[[colNm]])
      dat
        }


f1(df_a, "a")
#         a
#1   02.1.1
#2 02.1.1.1

f1(df_b, "a")
#         a
#1   02.1.1
#2 02.1.1.1
#3   02.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

could you not use the stringr package and do something like
`df_b <- str_replace(df_b$a, "0$", "1")`

this looks for the 0 at the end of the string and replaces it with a 1. Just note that you have to do the conversion to a character as it does not work on factors using 
`df_b$a <- as.character(df_b$a)`